# why I can't insert this record to mysql database?

Tags: c++, mysql

I want to insert a record into mysql database using mysql++, I print the result and get the following message:

Query:

```
INSERT INTO top_ten_dns_summary VALUES 
(1,google.com,124,29,4,2013-03-24 17:28:32,1969-12-31 17:00:00);
```

Query error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '17:28:32,1969-12-31 17:00:00)' at line 1

---

This is my top_ten_dns_summar table:

```
CREATE TABLE top_ten_dns_summary
(
    rank  INT,
    domain_name VARCHAR(20),
    avg_avg_query_time INT,
    stdev_query_time INT,
    numbers_of_query INT,
    start_time_stamp TIMESTAMP, 
    end_time_stamp TIMESTAMP
);
```

---

I am not familiar with database, so can anyone give me some clue? I doubt it's because of the data type error.

Answer (score 4):

String literals should be delimited by single quotes in mysql, like `'2013-03-24 17:28:32'`

Comment: I want to add some code here that I didn't pass a string to database,but a mysql::DataTime oject to iostream. Here is my code:query<<"INSERT INTO "<<"top_ten_dns_summary VALUES ("<<rank<<","<<domain_name<<","<<stat.avg_query_time<<","
                <<stat.stdev_query_time<<","<<stat.numbers_of_query<<","<<mysqlpp::DateTime (stat.start_time_stamp)<<","
                <<mysqlpp::DateTime (stat.end_time_stamp)<<");";

Comment: @user2172495: have you checked what actually `mysqlpp::DateTime()` returns?

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO top_ten_dns_summary VALUES 
(1,'google.com',124,29,4,'2013-03-24 17:28:32','1969-12-31 17:00:00');
```

Comment: Ok, I will try and see the result. Thank you.

Comment: It's Ok now. That really help